# How to change the date format in jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime, date, datetime-format

I am receiving date in  `2012-01-15T13:08:33+0000` How I can change it in other formats. Is there any built-in function of jquery or JavaScript..

Comment: would this help you: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Comment: Is there any Jquery built-in function to parse the date?

Comment: I think it would be useful here to get some idea of your target format set(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First [parse](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) the date, and then [format](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery dateFormat](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) plugin. You need to load that explicitly.